# get the changes(e.g create account, add contact, new value entered in the field ) made by user in the org in salesforce

Tags: lightning-events

What are the possible ways in salesforce so that i can get the field record changes in the org.
i want to get the changes made by user to certain field and send it to a group in a chattool.
How can i get those recent changes?
is there any ways other than trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up the [Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/) to capture changes directly in the third-party system, if supported, or you can use the [Streaming API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/intro_stream.htm) to specify queries to subscribe to, etc. You can also use [Workflow Outbound Messaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_understanding.htm), or use a Flow, etc. In other words, there's a large array of options available outside of triggers.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox ... I will try and implement one of this